# adding XY data from SQL database table in client application using Arcgis Javascript

Tags: sql, arcgis, arcgis-server, arcgis-js-api

I am trying to figure out how to take lat/lon information from a SQL database table and use that information to create a map layer using the ArcGIS javascript API.

My understanding is that in order to import layers to a map, that data needs to come from a web service.  I have and ArcGIS Server/Portal in which I can publish and store map services as an admin, but there is no intuitive to create map layers from a client application outside of pulling data from a map service.

As of now, I registered one of our SQL databases so the server will recognize the DB as a workspace, but I do not know how to reference the SQL table and pull it into a data class in which I can convert the table into an XY layer to add to the map.

I saw that there is a "DataAdapterLayer" class and a [sample from ESRI](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/dataadapterfeaturelayer.html), but I was not clear as to how to use it (also, it does not work on my machine, it only works on the ESRI site).

Anybody have any clue as to how to add location data from an SQL table?  Would a DataAdapter Layer be my only option?  Is there a better way?